# Plot probability curve from trial data

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, statistics

In my program I have taken 1000 trial of rolling 50 dices & calculated Shannon's Entropy.

 I was able to plot the result graphically. Here it is:
[image]
But what I want is to plot a single probability curve (like binomial probability distribution curve) of those data. Like 0 to 6 scaling in x axis and the most probable point will get the highest peak (Like here around 2.55 is most probable).

Here is my program:

```
#Entropy in dice
import math
import pylab
import random
import numpy as np
def rollDie():
    """Returns a random int between 1 and 6"""
    return random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6])
def rollN(roll,trial):
    result = []
    entropy=[]
    
    c=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
    p=[0,0,0,0,0,0]
    
    for a in range(trial):
        
        s=0;P=0
        for i in range(roll):
            x=rollDie()
            result.append(x)
            for j in range(6):
            
                if(j+1==x):
                    p[j]+=1
                    break
            
        
        for k in range(6):
            p[k]=p[k]/roll
            P+=p[k]
            if(p[k]!=0):
                s+=-p[k]*math.log(p[k],2)
            
        entropy.append(s)
        p=np.linspace(0,10,trial)
    pylab.plot(p,entropy,'*')
    print(entropy)
    
rollN(50,1000)
```

Please help if you can. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to graph the probability distribution of the shannon's entropy of your dice rolls, or of the outcome of your dice rolls? Either way, a probability distribution is effectively a histogram ([matplotlib has one](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html)).

Comment: @Swier hi I want to graph the probability distribution.